# Chronoforms plugin display twice the form tag

Tags: joomla, phplist

I have a form generated by phplist. I succed to implement it in joomla with chronoforms component and I insert it in an article with choroforms plugin. The problem is that in source code the form tab appear twice and javascript show me an error.
Did you met this problem, what I did wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, it sounds like you copied the code from phplist and pasted it in the Chronoforms form HTML box. If so, you need to remove the form tags from that box. The form tags are generated by the extension when it displays a form. You will also need to put the URL in the "Submit URL" in the general tab of the form.

Comment: I did all of that but still two form tags appear :(

Comment: Can you post a link? How about the code you are using in the article?